# How do I interpret a WSDL with references to a namespace java: on a non-java client?

Tags: java, php, soap, nusoap

I'm trying to integrate against a SOAP web service, running on Apache Axis. The WSDL specifies a namespace with a URI, that looks like:

```
<xsd:schema
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:stns="java:dk.tdc.serviceproviderweb.datatypes"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="qualified"
  targetNamespace="java:dk.tdc.serviceproviderweb.datatypes">
```

On the client-side, I'm using PHP, so the namespace `xmlns:stns` is meaningless. I have some Java class files (and their sources), that seems to correspond to this namespace. How do I handle this in a meaningful way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet is the beginning of an XML schema that defines the contents of the "java:dk.tdc.serviceproviderweb.datatypes" namespace.  (The targetNamespace attribute indicates this).

So it shouldn't matter if you're handling this with java or PHP on the client side,
as long as the rest of this schema is valid.

Answer (score 1):

OK. It seems that I got confused by the fact that my client library had a bug, which made it choke on the wsdl. I switched from NuSOAP to php5's native soap library, and things works now.